# "undefined reference to `hdr_aodv::offset_'" error in Network simulator

Tags: linux, unix, network-programming, ns2

I am trying to make some improvements on AODV routing protocol using NS 2.35. I have made some changes in AODV.cc and AODV.h file. For making the changes effective, I have made the following three commands from the terminal inside NS 2.35 folder:

1. sudo su

2.make clean

3.make

Now I am having the following error:

```
trace/cmu-trace.o: In function `CMUTrace::format_aodv(Packet*, int)':
cmu-trace.cc:(.text+0x18b7): undefined reference to `hdr_aodv::offset_'
```

What is the solutions of this?

For more clarification I am providing the .cc file link here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1OEPsG0ILELWkcxQ254TEpoN3M/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Of course you must get an error... You have changed some print parameter that will be used in `cmu-trace.cc`.

I don't know what you wanted to do, but it's so clear that you shouldn't change those parameter from `fprintf`.

like here :

```
 fprintf(stderr,
             "%s%d\t%s%d\t%s%d\t%s%d\t%s%d\t%s%d\t%s%d\t%s%d\t%s%f\t%s%f\n",
             "src=",         index,
             "dst=",         rp->rp_dst,
             "nhops=",       rp->rp_hop_count+1,
             "opthops=",     opthops,
             "sumHops=",     sumHops,
             "sumGodHops=",  sumGodHops,
             "numRtsFound=", numRtsFound,
             "prevHop=",     ch->prev_hop_, 
             "t:",           CURRENT_TIME,
             "RTT=",         CURRENT_TIME - rp->rp_timestamp);

         fprintf(gspTraceFile,
             "%s%d\t%s%d\t%s%d\t%s%d\t%s%d\t%s%d\t%s%d\t%s%d\t%s%f\t%s%f\n",
             "src=",         index,
             "dst=",         rp->rp_dst,
             "nhops=",       rp->rp_hop_count+1,
             "opthops=",     opthops,
             "sumHops=",     sumHops,
             "sumGodHops=",  sumGodHops,
             "numRtsFound=", numRtsFound,
             "prevHop=",     ch->prev_hop_, 
             "t:",           CURRENT_TIME,
             "RTT=",         CURRENT_TIME - rp->rp_timestamp);
```

Say exactly what do you want to do so maybe i could help you or maybe others help you.